# Check if flash enabled in Firefox version 59

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, apache-flex

How can I check if flash is enabled in Firefox browser? This is the code I am using

```
try {
    hasFlash = Boolean(new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'));
} catch(exception) {
    hasFlash = ('undefined' != typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']);
}
```

It always end up in exception and the 'hasFlash' flag turns to true even if flash is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The below one works for me :

```
let hasFlash = false;
try {
  let fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if(fo) hasFlash = true;
}catch(e){
  if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
}
```

Do check https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject

Comment: still getting true in firefox

Comment: i am checking from browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
hasFlash = navigator.plugins.namedItem('Shockwave Flash') != null;
```

All installed and enabled plugins are present in **navigator.plugin** list.

Comment: Hmm are you sure plugin is disabled in your browser? It work on my system with firefox 57, i check with 59..